# Is it possible to pass conditionals or other javascript as arguments in ember handlebars?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

I would like to pass a true/false statement to my handlebars

```
{{Gd-text-input label="Specify" name="Specify" key="entry.810220554" hideIf="entry.18110 === "Client""}}
```

I would like hideIf to be true if the variable entry.18110 is set to "Client

Answer (score 1):

First, add this somewhere -

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('ifEqual', function (var1, var2, options) {
    if (var1=== var2) {
        return new Handlebars.SafeString(options.fn(this));
    }
    return new Handlebars.SafeString(options.inverse(this));
});
```

Then..

```
{{#ifEqual entry.18110 "Client"}}
{{Gd-text-input label="Specify" name="Specify" key="entry.810220554" hideIf="true"}}
{{else}}
{{Gd-text-input label="Specify" name="Specify" key="entry.810220554" hideIf="false"}}
{{/if}}
```

This is pretty much the only way to do it, as the handlebars team has specifically left most logic out of the templates since it generally doesn't belong there. Which is debatable, as sometimes it makes things more complicated not to allow simple logic. But, this is very workaroundable.

Comment: Could I somehow pass two arguments to the template and use them to perform the test?

Comment: By template I assume you mean the "Gd-text-input". Yes, you could - as long as you have control over the Handlebars helper.

Comment: I tired to do this with the didInsertElement – event, but it only seems to fire once even though I have four instances of the template.

Comment: @KristofferNolgren I think if the `entry.18110` change the template isn't updated right? Because the `Handlebars.registerHelper` doesn't create bound helpers

Comment: This won't work, it will break when the value changes.  Ember handlebars binding will have an issue with the above implementation.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer does not work for Ember Handlebars, for your case you could do something like this.

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/agewuxAT/3/edit

Component

```
App.HideableCompComponent = Em.Component.extend({
  isHidden: function(){
    var prop = this.get('hideIfProperty');
    if(!prop) return false;
    // allow lazy comparison? up to you
    return this.get('content').get(prop) == this.get('hideIfValue');
  }.property('hideIfProperty', 'hideIfValue')
});
```

Template

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="components/hideable-comp">
  {{#unless isHidden}}
    I am a component I am not hidden!
  {{else}}
    I am hidden
  {{/unless}}
</script>
```

Usage

```
{{hideable-comp content=model hideIfProperty='length' hideIfValue=3}}
```

Comment: what does content=model mean in this approach?

Comment: the model on the controller returned from the index model hook `['red', 'yellow', 'blue']`