# Parameters of a custom ember block helper

Tags: ember.js, coffeescript, haml

I'm writing a simple restaurant menu and I need to check if two values are equal inside of handlebars template. To be more specific, I have bunch of `dish` models which have a `category_id` field. So I need to show a `dish` if it has the same `category_id` as category in which we are now.

And I have the following helper:

```
Em.Handlebars.registerHelper 'ifEqual', (v1, v2) -> 
  # debugging
  console.log v1, v2
  return v1 == v2
```

and I use it this way:

```
.categories
  =hb 'each c in categories' do
    %ul
      %li=hb 'c.name'
        =hb 'each d in dishes' do
          %ul
            =hb 'ifEqual d.category_id c.id' do
              %li=hb 'd.name'
```

(Sorry for hamlbars and coffeescript, but it should be pretty clear)

The problem is that `console.log` outputs strings `"d.category_id"` and `"c.id"` and I have no idea why it work this way.

On the other hand following non-block helper works pretty nice and outputs actual values

```
Em.Handlebars.helper 'console-log', (v1, v2) -> 
  console.log typeof(v1), v1
  console.log typeof(v2), v2
```

Any ideas why it works this way and what I've done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to save you time upfront, that won't work in ember handlebars, you'll need to add the logic to the controller and just use if/unless.

[Is it possible to pass conditionals or other javascript as arguments in ember handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330130/is-it-possible-to-pass-conditionals-or-other-javascript-as-arguments-in-ember-ha)

Comment: Hmm... I don't know how to let the controller know which `id` of the category we have now. How to access it?