# Ember JS If Condition using object attributes

Tags: ember.js

My object Pergunta have this format:

```
App.Pergunta = DS.Model.extend({
idQuestionario: DS.belongsTo('questionario'),
tipoResposta: DS.attr('number'),
posicao: DS.attr('number'),
pergunta: DS.attr(),
respostas: DS.attr(),
valorMinimo: DS.attr('number'),
valorMaximo: DS.attr('number')});
```

And i need to use attribute tipoResposta to compare if it's equal 1, and i've made the code bellow

HTML:

```
{{#each pregunta in controller}}
   {{#ifCond pregunta 1}}
      <p><h3>{{pregunta.id}} {{pregunta.posicao}}</h3></p>
   {{/ifCond}}
{{/each}}
```

JS

```
Ember.Handlebars.registerHelper('ifCond', function(v1, v2, options) {
  if(v1.tipoResposta === v2) {
    return options.fn(this);  
  }
  return options.inverse(this);
});
```

But using this code i can't send pregunta like an object but only like text.

Someone can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When creating `bound` helpers you need to register them as bound helpers using `Ember.Handlebars.registerBoundHelper(...)`.

That being said, registering bound helpers with block conditions isn't supported and will appear to work, but won't end up working.  The moment the bound variable changes and switches which block should be applied the application will crash complaining about how it isn't supported.

See [Is it possible to pass conditionals or other javascript as arguments in ember handlebars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330130/is-it-possible-to-pass-conditionals-or-other-javascript-as-arguments-in-ember-ha/20336544#20336544)